# c++ struct operator: conversion from to non-scalar type requested

Tags: c++, struct, type-conversion, operator-overloading

What I want to do is defining a structure equal operator. But it seems there is something wrong with that. How to fix this code?

```
struct Rectangle
{
public:
    double w;
    double h;
    Rectangle& operator=(int wh)
    {
        w=wh;
        h=wh;
        return *this;
    } 
};

int main()
{
    Rectangle rect=5;
    return 0;
}
```

command:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
```

Error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:16:17: error: conversion from ‘int’ to non-scalar type ‘Rectangle’ requested
  Rectangle rect=5;
                 ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the code as you have it you'll need to specify an appropriate constructor taking an `int` as well

```
struct Rectangle {
public:
    double w;
    double h;
    Rectangle(int wh) {
        w=wh;
        h=wh;
    } 
};
```

The assignment operator isn't called on initialization of that variable.

```
Rectangle rect=5; // Constructor call
Rectangle rect2; 
rect2 = 5; // Assignment operator call
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Rectangle rect=5;
```

To make this statement valid you have to provide *single argument non-explicit constructor*.

```
struct Rectangle
{
public:
    Rectangle(int x) {}
}
```

Remember that `Rectangle rect=5` is a call to constructor rather than assignment operator.

However, you can also do away with your functions if you slightly modify your call:-

```
Rectangle rect1;
rect1 = 5;
```

Comment: Couldn't he just do the assignment as a separate statement? `Rectangle rect; rect = 5;`?

Comment: Well mate assignment is meaningful for objects of same type...Although you can provide anything but it's better not to deviate from standard.

Comment: The overloaded assignment operator he defined won't work for that?